# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment: 'There was a problem while playing' error after some time

Tags: android-fragments, android-youtube-api, youtubeplayer

I'm getting this error after destroying and recreating the activity three times:

```
         "There was a problem while playing (Playback ID: ....) Tap to retry"
```

The following are the details and steps to reproduce the issue:

My app for Android (Match4app) is a card game which shows images and videos in each card.
These videos are shown using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.
In a deck of cards, each card is a fragment. 
Everytime a card is shown, the fragment's card creates a new instance of YouTubePlayerSupportFragment with its respective youTubePlayerFragment.initialize method:

```
youTubePlayerFragment.initialize( Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY,new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {

                YPlayer = player;                    
                YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle style = YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL;
                YPlayer.setPlayerStyle(style);
                YPlayer.setFullscreen(false);                        
                YPlayer.loadVideo(videoIDStatic);                       

            }               
        }
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {                
        }
    });
```

Users can jump from one card (fragment) to another card (fragment) in the same deck (Activity), and videos play well all the time. Users can watch up to 30 cards (with its respective videos). Everytime there is a jump from one card to another card, the Youtubleplayer is released and set to null with this method:

```
public void stopVideo(){
    if (YPlayer != null) {            
        YPlayer.release();
        YPlayer = null;
        if (!isAdded()) return;                                   
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

When jumping to another card, the fragment's card creates a new instance of YouTubePlayerSupportFragment with its respective youTubePlayerFragment.initialize method again.

Now, if user returns to main menu and the activity (deck) is destroyed (after running stopVideo() ), user can reopen the same activity and repeat all these tasks. HOWEVER, I have this strange issue:

1. Open Activity
2. Watch videos of the cards --> Videos play well (you can watch up to 30 videos)
3. Go back to Main Menu (i.e. destroy the activity)
4. Reopen Activity
5. Watch videos of the cards --> Videos play well (you can watch up to 30 videos)
6. Go back to Main Menu (i.e. destroy the activity)
7. Reopen Activity
8. Watch videos of the cards --> Videos play well (you can watch up to 30 videos)
9. Go back to Main Menu (i.e. destroy the activity)
10. Reopen Activity
11. Watch videos of the cards --> ALL VIDEOS START TO SHOW THIS MESSAGE:

    ```
     "There was a problem while playing (Playback ID: ....) Tap to retry"
    ```

Similar issue has been reported in this thread without solution:
[YouTubePlayerSupportFragment not playing Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546504/youtubeplayersupportfragment-not-playing-video)

Answer (score 0):

After fixing a memory leak in my app, the error does not longer appear.

So, it is safe to say that when playing a video, Youtube SDK checks whether there is enough memory. If there is no memory, the generic error is shown:

```
There was a problem while playing (Playback ID: ....) Tap to retry
```